# React Native android credit card scanning

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create Credit card scanning using React Native android version . I have been tried with React-native-card-io and react-native-awesome-card-io both not working Please guide me on this.

I am using google API 24 in my emulator

Comment: post what you done so far

Comment: I created app using react-native init cardscan . after project created used npm-install react-native-card-io . and tried access var CardIO = require('react-native-card-io'); but not working

Answer (score 1):

The CardIOView is actually a view that auto-loads into the camera. Keep in mind that this WILL NOT work on the simulator. I added the `<CardIOView />` to a separate page in my app so that as soon as you go to that page you can scan the credit card. After scanning I navigate back to where I was.

The example they provide works. Just need to understand what the component itself does. As soon as I got that it made total sense. Hope this helps.